# What kind of noun is "Bookkeeping"?

Tags: nouns, gerunds, compound-words

It's not a gerund since "bookkeep" isn't a verb, is it?

Is "bookkeep" a verb?

Please, can someone help me understand the properties of this word? Is it, for example, a compound noun?

Comment: Hm... "keep" is a verb, and "keeping" is a gerund... and "bookkeeping" means "keeping book[s]"... Is there a word for constructions in which the verb and object are combined as a gerund but not commonly as a verb? "Goaltending..." "haircutting" (never mind that "haircut" is a noun of its own...)

Comment: It's certainly a [compound noun](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/compound-nouns), formed from "bookkeeping" (compound nouns are normally formed with a noun as the final component). [This article](https://editorsmanual.com/articles/gerunds/) discusses how "gerunds can form compound nouns". But no particular name for them.

Comment: I muck prefer book-keeping. Those double Ks look ugly.

Comment: The double k's are beautiful. Name me one other word that has three consecutive double letters.

Comment: Sutar's example looked to me like go-alt-ending

Comment: @Pete subbookkeeper has four.

Comment: I don't know what kind of goal is "tended", but one sort is kept by a goalkeeper, so there's goalkeeping. I'd analyse the noun as a verb's object and that verb's gerund, the verb being the simple one. Other examples: house/peace/safe/beekeeping, fundraising, factfinding.

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=participial+adjectives+pseudo) has: << **pseudo-participial**: [adjective] [linguistics] Having the form of a participial of a verb, but for which no such verb exists. For example, for the adjective _yellow-bellied_ there is no corresponding verb "[to] _yellow-belly_". >> This concept, if not terminology, surely extends to the ing-form _bookkeeping_.  Morphologically, it's a compound noun, formed like _bee keeping_, _stamp collecting_, but of solid form. It's non-count in usage. Bottom line ... it's just a noun.

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know, "bookkeep" is not a word. But "bookkeeping" and "bookkeeper" are. Here is some more info that might help: [bookkeeper etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bookkeeper#:%7E:text=bookkeeper%20(n.)&text=%2B%20keeper.&text=Related%3A%20Bookkeeping%2C%20which%20is%20from,a%20back%2Dformation%20from%201886.)